# "Sidecar" containers in Kubernetes pods

Tags: kubernetes

I'd like a multi-container pod with a couple of components:

- A "main" container which contains a build job
- A "sidecar" container which contains an HTTP proxy, used by the "main" container

This seems to fit well with the pod design philosophy as [described in the Kubernetes documentation](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/pods/#uses-of-pods), but I believe so long as the "sidecar" runs, the pod is kept alive. In my case, the "main" container is not long-lived; once it exits, the "sidecar" should be terminated.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 23):

A pod is running as long as one of the containers is running.  If you need them to exit together, you have to arrange that the sidecar dies.  We do not have a notion of "primary" vs "secondary" containers wrt lifecycle, though that's sort of interesting.

One option would be to use an emptyDir volume and write a file telling the sidecar "time to go".  The sidecar would exit when it sees that file.

Comment: In my case the problem is the side car is not completely under my control -- it's a service from a third party (closed source), so I don't know how to arrange for this service to stop except if it were possible to send a signal to its process.

Comment: A common pattern is to use this container as a base image for your own image (dockerfile FROM).  Add a script and change the entrypoint to this script, and do something like: run "real" app in background, while file /pod/exit-now does not exist, sleep 3 seconds; loop; kill real app

Comment: Also, there is a new KEP to teach k8s about "main" containers.  I have not reviewed it et, but there is a clear need.

Comment: Great idea, thank you for sharing.  I ended up with something similar -- turned on shared process namespace and then the "worker" container sends SIGTERM to the other container that is out of my control (this, however, did not completely solve my problem, cause the app that received SIGTERM exited with non-zero code and the job that owned the pod was in some weird state [I do not recall now exactly which ATM]).

Answer (score 6):

For anyone still looking for an answer to this, the sidecar feature is being developed and should be out in v1.17 of Kubernetes, which will have this exact requested behaviour.

From the proposal:

> One-line enhancement description: Containers can now be a marked as sidecars so that they startup before normal containers and shutdown after all other containers have terminated.

https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/753

UPDATE: looks like it's planned for v1.18 now

Comment: In case anyone gets here years later: This feature is not coming.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/jobs/ resource?

Comment: Yes, these pods are running under a job. But I think so long as the "sidecar" container stays up, the job will remain running.

Answer (score 1):

The feature might not have been available when the question was asked but, one can define postStart and preStop handlers for pod now. You could probably define preStop in your main container to kill sidecar container.

Answer (score 1):

[Sidecar Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/sidecar-containers/) is in beta since v1.29

> If an init container is created with its restartPolicy set to Always, it will start and remain running during the entire life of the Pod ...
> This feature is also useful for running Jobs with sidecars, as the sidecar container will not prevent the Job from completing after the main container has finished.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the liveness probe to help with this. The probe checks for the "main" container (as well as any of its own checks). Once the main container goes down, the liveness probe fails, and then the pod should be recycled.

Comment: however keep in mind it will mark the pod as failed, in case that's a factor in your setup

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but creating a volume just for this purpose seemed too much.

Another way that I came up with is to create liveness probes for each container.

The liveness prob of the main container would act normally, succeed when the container is alive, and fail when the container dies.

The liveness of the sidecar however you implement it in a way that always fails.

This makes the liveness of the whole pod only dependent on the liveness of the main container, so when the main container dies the whole pod dies, and as long as the main container is alive the whole pod will stay alive.