# Kubernetes restart multi-container pod if a container dies

Tags: kubernetes

I am using Kubernetes v1.7 to run a multi-container pod - an app container and a sidecar. I want to restart the pod in case the app container dies.
How to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Sidecar" containers in Kubernetes pods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38600622/sidecar-containers-in-kubernetes-pods)