# How to configure a multi-container k8s pod to terminate the whole pod if [X] container terminates?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a multi-container pod that has one main container and another supporting container. The main container terminates after completing its process, but the pod stays in "RUNNING" state because the other container is still running. How can I configure Kubernetes to terminate the whole pod (or the other container and subsequently the whole pod) when my main container terminates?

Comment: Just saw - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38600622/sidecar-containers-in-kubernetes-pods from 5 years ago. Have there been any updates in Kubernetes that allow it more directly rather than the slightly hacky way mentioned in the answer?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you deploy it?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak 1.18.20

Comment: How did you run your cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor?

Comment: it is run on a cloud provider, yes

Comment: Which cloud providor did you use?

Comment: Why is that relevant?

Comment: To replicate your problem as close as possible.

Answer (score 0):

with [shared pid namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/share-process-namespace/) you can actually "see" the other process from your sidecar, having that you can track pid of the process you want to react to and exit/restart when that pid changes